# What regularity on a function when composed with an absolutely continuous makes the composition measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $g:[0,T] \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $T>0$ and let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to [0,+\infty)$.

I know that $g(\cdot)$ is absolutely continuous, and I want to know under what assumptions on $f(\cdot)$ the composition $f \circ g$ is a measurable function? (the underlying measurable space is Lebesgue measurable).

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: $g$ is measurable. What makes $f\circ g$ measurable?

Comment: @KurtG. Could you please elaborate? I was asking the same question.

Comment: It was a hint. :) Did we not learn that the composition of measurable functions is measurable?

Comment: @KurtG. Yes, you are correct. However, several pathologies come into the picture when the functions are Lebesgue measurable functions (If the functions are Borel measurable then we can avoid those pathologies). I may be incorrect, so could you please point me to a source where I can find this? Thank you.

Comment: [Usual suspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Properties). Absolutely continuous $\Rightarrow$ continuous $\Rightarrow$ Borel measurable, as we know.

Comment: @KurtG. Right. So all we need is f to be Borel measurable, and I can at least assert that the composition is Borel measurable.